# How to Convert a String returned from JSON to Object Dot Notation In C# & JSON.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I'm using C# and JSON.Net to read this JSON document:

```
{
    "myValue": "foo.bar.baz"
}
```

My goal is to use the string value "foo.bar.baz" as object dot notation to access the value of foo.bar.baz in the foo object:

```
public Foo foo = new Foo();

var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Nobody");
var json = client.DownloadString(new Uri("http://www.example.com/myjson.json"));
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach (JProperty prop in o.Children<JProperty>()){

    Response.Write(????); // should write "Hello World!"

}
```

Just for reference, here is the Foo class:

```
public class Foo {
        public Foo() {
        this.bar = new Foo();
        this.bar.baz = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an object with a property named `foo`, you could use reflection to find the value you are looking for. This would work for fields, but don't do that, use public properties instead.

```
public class SomeContainer
{
    public Foo foo { get; set; }
}

var container = new SomeContainer();

var myValuePath = "foo.bar.baz"; // Get this from the json

string[] propertyNames = myValuePath.Split('.');

object instance = container;
foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames)
{
    var instanceType = instance.GetType();

    // Get the property info
    var property = instanceType.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // Get the value using the property info. 'null' is passed instead of an indexer
    instance = property.GetValue(instance, null);
}

// instance will be baz after this loop
```

There are all sorts of potential `NullReferenceException` so you'll have to code this more defensively. However, this should be a good start for you.

Comment: Thanks, that works. As you mentioned, there there are all sorts of potential NullReferenceExceptions. Is it a bad idea to do what I'm asking? Seems very complicated.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish... However, it's not the worst idea if used wisely. You must trust the supply of JSON or you give away access to your app internals. Using reflection like this isn't very fast so don't do it millions of times in a critical path.